# How to get quickbooks online profit and loss report using API

Tags: php, report, quickbooks-online

I want to get Profit and Loss repport from quickbooks online using API.
I googled about it, i found that quickbooks online not supporting reports through API.
I think quick books recently exposed the reports through API. check
[The QuickBooks Online Reports API has arrived!](https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/03/25/the-quickbooks-online-reports-api-has-arrived)

I didn't find how to get these reports using the [php sdk](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php)

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports/profitandloss

Comment: Yes i seen that doc. i'm new to quickbooks. i'm using https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3 for integration. I didn't find the example for reports. So the new ipp v3 supports reports through API right ?

Answer (score 0):

QBO Reports APIs are released recently in production. JAVA/.NET devkits support these(PHP devkit doesn't support JSON response, whereas reports API return only JSON. That's why, as of now PHP devkit can't be used here).

You can have a look at the following links on Reports API

https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/03/25/the-quickbooks-online-reports-api-has-arrived

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the links above before posting the question. Do you have an idea when the reports will be updated in php sdk.

Comment: No. I don't know yet. But if I get any news on it, then I'll update this post asap. Thanks